# Practical Basics of Charging a Battery

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, battery-chemistry

I see that this question has been asked many times, but I just wanted to get a better overview, rather than asking about another individual situation.

**When selecting a battery charger, what ratings must I know (from both the charger and the battery)?** For example, I know that when *discharging* a battery, the voltage must be the same, but the maximum current rating can be *higher* because the *load* is the one that determines how many amps it draws. But then you must also be sure that the battery can discharge that much current in a given time. Do similar rules apply to charging?

Comment: There are a few completely different battery chemistries but you did not say which one you have. If you use a charger designed for a different type of battery then the battery and/or charger might explode or catch on fire.

Comment: @Addioguru well, I was originally asking for a small 12v 7ah SLA battery, but I'm also interested in LiPos for RC vehicles. I know that they require completely different types of chargers, but the "rules" to charging them would be the same, apart from the difference in ratings of the batteries, right?

Comment: I suggest to search for the explicit statement that the given charger supports the given battery type.

Comment: An antique lead-acid battery is charged at its rated charging current until a certain voltage is reached then the charger is turned off or a trickle charge continues. A modern Lithium battery is charged at its rated charging current and the charger limits the charging voltage to 4.2V per cell for older liythium batteries, then the charging current is monitored and the charger is disconnected then the charging current becomes low. No trickle charging.

Comment: @Galaxy no not really, different battery types have different "rules", and there is even multiple different ways to determine when NiMH batteries are full. But basically, don't exceed rated safe charging current and don't exceed rated safe voltage. The similarities end approximately there. SLA batteries can be left at floating voltage in the end. Lithiums can explode if left on float charge and charging must be terminated when the charge current is small enough.

Comment: Stack exchange sites are reserved only for *specific* questions.  For a general overview, you need to use traditional reference materials.  The question you have posted is not specifically answerable, and as such is not allowed here.  In practical terms, buy a charger for the battery type, cell count, and capacity you intend to use.

Comment: @Justme Oh ok, that makes sense.

Comment: @ChrisStratton really? On other forums, I've had my questions shunned because they were focused on a specific situation. Anyways thanks for the advice.

Comment: Google "battery university"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When selecting a battery charger, what ratings must I know (from both
> the charger and the battery)?

1. Charging algorithm must match the battery type.
2. Charger nominal voltage / number of cells must match the battery.
3. Charging current must not exceed the battery's charge current rating.

That's the basics, but in practice it is complicated due to the many different types of battery and ways they can be charged. Most batteries normally take a long time to charge, and people are impatient, so methods of charging faster have been developed to get the maximum charge into a specific battery in the shortest possible time. If applied incorrectly this could damage the battery and perhaps make it leak or explode.

For example, Nicad and NiMH batteries are usually rated for a 'trickle' charging current of 1/10 'C' (ie. Ah capacity / 10) for 12-14 hours. The charger regulates current, but does not limit voltage - it just puts out enough to keep the current going. This ensures that each cell gets a full charge no matter what state of charge it started with, at a low enough current to not overheat even when 'dumping' the excess energy as heat.

But 12-14 hours is a long time to wait, and unnecessary if the battery is already partly charged, so 'fast' charging algorithms were developed that use various methods of terminating the charge before the battery gets too hot. The charger may use a temperature sensor, or monitor battery voltage and cut off when a slight voltage dip is detected ('Delta V'), or it might just charge for a fixed time and rely on the battery having a matched capacity and being fully discharged before recharging, and/or
reduce charge current as the voltage rises.

'High capacity' batteries have thinner plates that can't handle as much current as 'high current' batteries, so their maximum 'fast' charging rate is correspondingly lower. Delta V detection is less reliable at lower charge rates due to the smaller voltage change, so a 'high capacity' battery may also require a different charging algorithm. NiMH batteries have lower Delta-V than Nicad, and often 'false peak' a few minutes into the charge, so a charger designed for both types must take this into account.

Finally, although 'trickle' charging is supposed to be safe for any Nicad or NiMH battery, Nicad batteries suffer 'voltage depression' if overcharged for a long time, which can only be (partially) reversed by deep cycling them several times.

Lead acid and Lithium batteries (of which there are several different subtypes) have quite different charging requirements that also vary depending on how fast they are charged and what applications they are used in. Unlike Nicad/NiMH, maximum charge voltage is very critical and varies with different chemistries. Extra safety precautions must be taken because these batteries can easily explode if charged incorrectly.

So-called 'multi-chemistry' chargers can be programmed to suit different battery types. With these you generally have to set the correct charging current for your battery, as well as the specific battery type. Some chargers have an 'automatic' setting that attempts to determine the maximum safe charging current by monitoring internal resistance and/or voltage etc.

Many consumer products have a dedicated charger that is 'tuned' to the specific battery inside them, and the specs written on the charger often do not reflect the actual charge current and voltage.

Therefore, to ensure that any battery gets charged correctly you *must* carefully match the charger to the battery's specifications *and* the specific battery type. Just staying below the rated charge current may not be enough, but in some circumstances you may be able to exceed it *if* you fully understand the characteristics of your battery.